# Java regex program not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, multiline

On running this program,

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class PatternExample {
    public static final String numbers = "1\n22\n333\n4444\n55555\n666666\n7777777\n88888888\n999999999\n0000000000";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("9.*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(numbers);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Start index: 44 End index: 53 999999999
```

I expected the output include the zeros, because of `Pattern.MULTILINE`.
What should I do to include the zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `DOTALL` flag (and don't need the `MULTILINE` flag which only applies to the behaviour of `^` and `$`):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("9.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This is stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt)

> The regular expression `.` matches any character except a line terminator unless the `DOTALL` flag is specified.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Pattern.DOTALL`, use the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("9.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Also `Pattern.MULTILINE` is not necessary here since you are not using any start `^` and end `$` anchors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the flag `Pattern.DOTALL`. By default, `.` [does not match line terminators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).